# Laravel spatie table column extend

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

In role_has_permissions table have 3 column, I want to add one more column. The column name is company id

```
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');

        $table->string('model_type');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger($columnNames['model_morph_key']);
```

Any way to add this

Answer (score 0):

@MDMasum If I understand what you are asking right, then I believe you could add another column by generating another migration on the existing table.  I am not familiar with Spatie, but I knowing Laravel, I don't see why this would not work.

You could do so with the following artisan command in CLI:

```
php artisan make:migration add_company_id_to_role_has_permissions_table --table=role_has_permissions
```

You will get a generated migration file that is named something similar to this:
2020_09_03_012345_add_company_id_to_role_has_permissions_table.php

Then modify the up function in that generated migration file accordingly.

Finally, run the following artisan command in CLI:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: How can i add value on this table ?

Comment: @MDMasum from the controller into this this new field?

Comment: Yes sir, please let me know

Comment: Is the table a spatie generated table? I would look at the spatie package code and look for the other column names and how they are set there.  What is the spatie package you are using? Do you have a link to it that you can provide for clarity?

Comment: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction this one sir

Comment: @MDMasum See this part of the documentation: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/advanced-usage/extending#migrations---adding-fields-to-your-models   It explains what I already mentioned, but says you will need to extend the appropriate Spatie Model to be able to interact with any fields added. Have a look and see if that makes sense to you.